# VS Code not starting new terminal in current working directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04 and running into a strange problem. I have not changed the configuration for the `terminal.integrated.cwd` setting, so I expect it to launch the terminal in the current working directory. Instead, it launches the terminal in the current working directory's parent directory.

For example, let's say I launch VS Code from the following folder:

```sh
pwd
/home/rdawson/Coding/my-working-folder
code .
```

The above will launch VS Code with `my-working-folder` showing its files.  So far so good.  Now, when I click on `Terminal >> New Teriminal`, a new terminal window will open, but it opens in the `/home/rdawson/Coding` directory instead of the `/home/rdawson/Coding/my-working-folder` diretory.  I have to manually `cd` into the `my-working-folder` directory.  This is annoying and unexpected behavior.

I also opened VS Code and enabled tracing.  When I performed the same steps above, the following is what I saw:

```sh
[2020-09-07 06:29:49.251] [renderer1] [trace] IPty#spawn /bin/bash [] {"name":"xterm-256color","cwd":"/home/rdawson/Coding/my-working-folder","env":{"GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS":"JS ERROR;JS LOG","LESSOPEN":"| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s","USER":"rdawson","TEXTDOMAIN":"im-config","XDG_SEAT":"seat0","SSH_AGENT_PID":"1892","XDG_SESSION_TYPE":"x11","SHLVL":"1","OLDPWD":"/home/rdawson/Coding","QT4_IM_MODULE":"xim","HOME":"/home/rdawson","DESKTOP_SESSION":"ubuntu","NVM_BIN":"/home/rdawson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin","GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE":"ubuntu","GTK_MODULES":"gail:atk-bridge","DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS":"unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus","COLORTERM":"truecolor","NVM_DIR":"/home/rdawson/.nvm","IM_CONFIG_PHASE":"2","LOGNAME":"rdawson","GTK_IM_MODULE":"ibus","USERNAME":"rdawson","XDG_SESSION_ID":"3","TERM":"xterm-256color","GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID":"this-is-deprecated","WINDOWPATH":"2","PATH":"/home/rdawson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin","SESSION_MANAGER":"local/linux:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1796,unix/linux:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1796","XDG_MENU_PREFIX":"gnome-","GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN":"/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/069fd3dc_735e_47b3_8137_3f65efacb223","XDG_RUNTIME_DIR":"/run/user/1000/snap.code","DISPLAY":":1","LANG":"en_US.UTF-8","XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP":"Unity","LS_COLORS":"rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:","XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP":"ubuntu","XMODIFIERS":"@im=ibus","GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE":":1.141","XAUTHORITY":"/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority","SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh","GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR":"/snap/code/42/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas","DISABLE_WAYLAND":"1","SHELL":"/bin/bash","QT_ACCESSIBILITY":"1","GDMSESSION":"ubuntu","LESSCLOSE":"/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s","TEXTDOMAINDIR":"/usr/share/locale/","GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT":"stderr","GPG_AGENT_INFO":"/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1","XDG_VTNR":"2","QT_IM_MODULE":"ibus","PWD":"/home/rdawson/Coding/my-working-folder","CLUTTER_IM_MODULE":"xim","XDG_DATA_DIRS":"/usr/share/ubuntu:/home/rdawson/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop","XDG_CONFIG_DIRS":"/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg","VTE_VERSION":"5202","APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL":"true","CHROME_DESKTOP":"code-url-handler.desktop","ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP":"ubuntu:GNOME","TERM_PROGRAM":"vscode","TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION":"1.48.2","VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-dfe0817a77.sock","GIT_ASKPASS":"/snap/code/42/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh","VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE":"/snap/code/42/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/snap/code/42/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js"},"cols":157,"rows":2,"useConpty":false,"conptyInheritCursor":false}
```

Based on the log file, it seems VS Code is using the `OLDPWD` instead of `PWD`.  Anyone have a solution for this?  I also run VS Code on Windows 10 and do not encounter this problem.